# Improving my Ellipse Fitting Algorithm

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I'm hoping that I can get some help in improving my ellipse fitting method. I'm thinking of trying to use a RANSAC style method but I'm not sure if it is the right direction to go in. Any help on the direction I should begin going in would be greatly appreciated, even if it is just an improvement on my edge finding.

I've been working on this problem for a while, and I'm not making very much progress. I think the main problem is the quality of the images but I can only work which what I have now.

My current method I am testing is to use edge detection on the image, and then try and to fit ellipses around the edges I find. The images below will highlight my main problem which is that my method deals very poorly with noise.

Original Image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRYCD.jpg

After Canny Edge detection:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Yl8o.png

After Ellipse Fitting:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/waHzJ.jpg

Below is my code which I use. For the Canny edge detection I found some values and are using them statically for now. It is code taken from online which I have then modified, and is a bit hacky for now sorry.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cv2
import numpy as np
import sys
from numpy.linalg import eig, inv

# param is the result of canny edge detection
def process_image(img):
    # for every pixel in the image:
    for (x,y), intensity in np.ndenumerate(img):
        # if the pixel is part of an edge:
        if intensity == 255:
            # determine if the edge is similar to an ellipse
            ellipse_test(img, x, y)

def ellipse_test(img, i, j):
    #poor coding practice but what I'm doing for now
    global output, image
    i_array = []
    j_array = []
    # flood fill i,j while storing all unique i,j values in arrays
    flood_fill(img, i, j, i_array, j_array)
    i_array = np.array(i_array)
    j_array = np.array(j_array)
    if i_array.size >= 10:
        #put those values in a numpy array
        #which can have an ellipse fit around it
        array = []
        for i, elm in enumerate(i_array):
          array.append([int(j_array[i]), int(i_array[i])])
        array = np.array([array])
        ellp = cv2.fitEllipse(array)
        cv2.ellipse(image, ellp, (0,0,0))
        cv2.ellipse(output, ellp, (0,0,0))

def flood_fill(img, i, j, i_array, j_array):
    if img[i][j] != 255:
        return
    # store i,j values
    i_array.append(float(i))
    j_array.append(float(j))
    # mark i,j as 'visited'
    img[i][j] = 250
    # flood_fill adjacent and diagonal pixels

    (i_max, j_max) = img.shape

    if i - 1 > 0 and j - 1 > 0:
        flood_fill(img, i - 1, j - 1, i_array, j_array)
    if j - 1 > 0:
        flood_fill(img, i, j - 1, i_array, j_array)
    if i - 1 > 0:
        flood_fill(img, i - 1, j, i_array, j_array)
    if i + 1 < i_max and j + 1 < j_max:
        flood_fill(img, i + 1, j + 1, i_array, j_array)
    if j + 1 < j_max:
        flood_fill(img, i, j + 1, i_array, j_array)
    if i + 1 < i_max:
        flood_fill(img, i + 1, j, i_array, j_array)
    if i + 1 < i_max and j - 1 > 0:
        flood_fill(img, i + 1, j - 1, i_array, j_array)
    if i - 1 > 0 and j + 1 < j_max:
        flood_fill(img, i - 1, j + 1, i_array, j_array)

image = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1], 0)
canny_result = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (3,3), 0)
canny_result = cv2.Canny(canny_result, 107, 208,
    apertureSize=3, L2gradient=False)

#output is a blank images which the ellipses are drawn on
output = np.zeros(image.shape, np.uint8)
output[:] = [255]

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.namedWindow("Canny result:", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('Canny result:', canny_result)
print "Press any key to find the edges"
cv2.waitKey(0)
print "Now finding ellipses"

process_image(canny_result)
print "Ellipses found!"
cv2.namedWindow("Original image:", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('Original image:', image)

cv2.namedWindow("Output image:", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow("Output image:", output)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I tried, I use `dilate` and `scipy.ndimage` to do some process:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread("ellipse.jpg", 0)

bimage = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (3, 3), 0)
edge_image = cv2.Canny(bimage, 107, 208,
    apertureSize=3, L2gradient=False)

img2 = cv2.dilate(edge_image, np.ones((3, 3)), iterations=3)
dis_image = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

import scipy.ndimage as ndimage
labels, count = ndimage.label(img2)

for lab, idx in enumerate(ndimage.find_objects(labels.astype(int)), 1):
    sy = idx[0].start
    sx = idx[1].start
    y, x = np.where(labels[idx] == lab)
    ellp = cv2.fitEllipse(np.column_stack((x+sx, y+sy)))
    cv2.ellipse(dis_image, ellp, (0, 0, 255))
```

here is the output:

[image]